# How do I use a cgo-based package on Windows?

Tags: windows, go, build

The `regexp` in the Go's standard library is quite poor, so I need a more powerful engine, like regex in Python (pip install regex), supporting recursion, backref, look-ahead/behind, etc... .

I found:
https://godoc.org/github.com/dlclark/regexp2
.NET compatible, which was quite fine; however, recursion is not working properly.

and several bindings to PCRE, for example: 
https://godoc.org/github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre

so, how can I use this binding on Win64?

Comment: By the way, are you aware that Go has its `regexp` package implemented that way [for a reason](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)? To have an idea about what problems could be caused by RE engines allowing nondetermenistic RE's execution time, start with [this](http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016).

Comment: Yes, i read this. but i don't care. i have used regex module in python for parsing web pages in my self-written "spider"-bot. all were ok =) sometimes crash, rarely hang - usual issues.

Comment: on python i used multiprocessing, on go, i think i need something like aborting by timeout

Comment: by the way, regexp2 package from dlclark have timeout option. maybe it would be reasonable to ask dlclarck to fix recursion...

Comment: «sometimes crash, rarely hang - usual issues» -- I sincerely hope you don't work at NASA or on other mission-crictical software. "Let it crash early" is a good paradigm, but only when it's supported by the runtime which expects this to happen, and is able to recover. But it's named Erlang, not Python.

Comment: It happened quite rarely and was not critical, hung processes were terminated with error reporting. If 1 of 10K sites will not be processed - this is not so important. And yes, it was not NASA )

Comment: and process-based parallelism is quite a supports this paradigm "let it crash"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using C++ standard library `std::regex` (no third-party library). Wrap the logic in `try` block, use `catch(...){return ERROR;}` to catch any error, and declare the C function `extern "C"` so you can call with cgo.

---

From https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo (there is a part about Windows):

> In order to use cgo on Windows, you'll also need to first install a
>   gcc compiler (for instance, mingw-w64) and have gcc.exe (etc.) in your
>   PATH environment variable before compiling with cgo will work.

---

That being said, I still think you should consider sticking with the `regexp` package and try to make regular expressions as simple as possible. Because complicated regular expressions are likely to hurt readability of code. Another problem is sometimes they introduce subtle bugs which are difficult to spot and fix. So writing more code in Go instead of regex may actually make the life easier.

Comment: thx for the answer) but "complicated regular expressions are likely to hurt readability of code" - i use self-written regexp generator script for my tasks (for example, HTML parsing). it is easier to generate new than to edit existing.

Comment: Hey, I have a similar error message but with python, setup.py, and build as missing files. I have gcc and can use ```gcc -v hello.c```, and have compiled with it in the past. it doesn't say which files the errors are in though (I was trying to "get" directly from github). Do either of you have any ideas about what could help here?